# Did the pbf file format change?

Tags: routes, openstreetmap, osrm

everyone,

Until this year I used to upgrade OSRM routing data using the 'download-extract-contract' sequence. However, after the last upgrade routing daemon began to return HTTP code 400 and the following text:
`{"message":"Impossible route between points","code":"NoRoute"}`

I tried to download the new data again, but without success. One-year old data which I kept before upgrade, still return meaningful responses. When I tried to use new OSRM binaries (osrm/osrm-backend from Docker Hub), they also worked well.

Did the file format change? Are there any options other than upgrading the binaries?

Comment: There are no changes on the PBF file format as far as I known. Sounds more like a possible bugfix in OSRM. Any errors while processing the PBF file? Did you check the changelog between the two OSRM versions?

Comment: No, there were no errors during the processing. I didn't check the changelog, but searched for pbf-related issues in osrm-backend git repo.